# Internal Server Error in Codeigniter htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, localhost

I am new to codeigniter, I just want to switch from one page to another. I am using localhost and wamp server

## In config file:

`$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';`

I change it to

`$config['index_page'] = '';`

## In .htaccess file:

`Deny from all`

I change it to

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|stylesheets|scripts|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

and save this file in application, system and root directory.

Thanks in advance, kindly help me, really need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure mod_rewrite is enabled in php.ini file after that use this following into your htaccess file.

```
# Use PHP5CGI as default
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /yourprojectfolder/
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

replace yourprojectfolder with the name of your project folder when u save all application and system folders.

Answer (score 0):

All you done is right,just change your .htaccess code in the root directory like this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```